# R Functionals does not work when batch assigning names to variables

Tags: r, functional-programming, lapply, mapply

I want to use functionals to batch assign names to csv data files, I've tested functionals including `Map`, `mapply`, `lapply` with function `assign` for substituting `<-`, however all these functionals does not work and only traditional for loops work, could anyone explain this? Thanks in advance!

Here is my Code:

```
allData <- c("Actinomyces.csv", "Bacteria.csv", "COD.csv", "Fungi.csv", "NH3.csv", "NO2.csv", "NO3.csv", "TN.csv", "TP.csv")
#CSV files in the working path
csvs <- lapply(allData, read.csv)
#Store data frames into a list
nameList <- c("Actinomyces", "Bacteria", "COD", "Fungi", "NH3", "NO2", "NO3", "TN", "TP")
lapply(c(1:9), function(i){assign(nameList[i], csvs[[i]])})
#Doesn't work
Map(assign, nameList, csvs)
#Doesn't work either
mapply(assign, nameList, csvs)
#Doesn't work again
for (i in 1:9){
    assign(nameList[i], csvs[[i]])
}
#Only this works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two base R ways:

```
junk <- Map("assign", nameList, csvs, MoreArgs = list(.GlobalEnv))

list2env(setNames(csvs, nameList), .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 3):

A more typical R idiom for this task would be to start here:

```
csvs <- lapply(allData, read.csv)
```

and at this point your data is nicely stored in a list. If you want a named list, you can simply do:

```
nameList <- c("Actinomyces", "Bacteria", "COD", "Fungi", "NH3", "NO2", "NO3", "TN", "TP")
csvs <- setNames(csvs, nameList)
```

And then you can refer to any of the data sets by name via `csvs[["COD"]]`, eg.